# How to interpolate grid data to finer resolution on the fly using make_geocube

Tags: python, datagrid, grid, geopandas

I have a geodataframe with many columns of data that I am compiling into a geocube.

The geodataframe has cell geometry in one column, and each other column contains data for that cell.

I have no issues creating the geocube using make_geocube from from geocube.api.core import make_geocube

This is an example:

data_cube = make_geocube(vector_data = gdf_sub, resolution = (100,-100))

What I am trying to do is to specify a smaller resolution of (1, -1) into the geocube, and to specify the interpolation method as linear (or bilinear).

I have seen documentation where people do something like the following:

data_cube = make_geocube(vector_data = gdf_sub, resolution = (1,-1), rasterize_function=rasterize_points_griddata(method="linear"))

However this gives error:

rasterize_points_griddata() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'geometry_array', 'data_values', 'grid_coords', and 'fill'

Based on documentation, I can't see why this method isn't working.

Any ideas?